# Does the order of conditions in WHERE clause matter in relation to composite index?

Tags: mysql, database

The case is in MySQL. Assume I have table `students` with columns `serial`, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `class_number`. There is a composite index `idx_serial_first_name (serial, first_name)`. If I have a query like the one below, will the composite index be hit?

```sql
SELECT serial, first_name, last_name FROM students WHERE first_name = "Jhon" AND serial = "abc123";
```

Or should the query be like this:

```sql
SELECT serial, first_name, last_name FROM students WHERE serial = "abc123" AND first_name = "Jhon";
```

Does the order of conditions in `WHERE` clause in a query matter to determine whether the index is hot or not?
Thank you.

Comment: "Does the order of conditions in WHERE clause matter in relation to composite index?" - No.

Comment: @dev-x  Please test your queries with WHERE MATCHED sequence and WHERE UNMATCHED sequence and let us know how long your queries take when testing substantial table sizes.  EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); will show you when indexes are considered and which index is used.  Sometimes the optimizer gets a little confused.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html